# Confusion about HTML Box Model

Tags: html, css

I haven't developed much in HTML/CSS in some time and was looking at some old code and came across the following:
CSS:

```
#menu{
float: right;
height: 80%;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.filler{
float: right;
height: 50%;
}

p.clear{clear: both; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="filler">
    <p class="clear"></p>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <p class="clear"></p>
</div>
```

These div classes are nested inside a banner div and lie in the top right corner of the screen. Without the `<div class="filler">` the menu div no longer lies within the banner div, nor at the top right of the screen. What is going on? I want to design a webpage with as little nested divs as possible. Is there a way to accomplish this same functionality without having a div that contains nothing but height?

Comment: Can you please supply a link to what you're developing? bit hard to assist without viewing the problem, maybe try and replicate the problem is jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the old trick here is on the p.clear having 0 height. I kinda see whats going on tho you're excluding alot of variables.  Anyway.  If you want a prematop right menu you could try something like :

```
#menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I remember getting this from an old tutorial. I don't know why I didn't think about this answer. The tutorial was obviously overcomplicating things.

Comment: Never a problem, always remember, the biggest mistake we often make as coders is over-complicating things.  If the answer seems over-complicated and is taking to long to figure out, step away from it and you'll probably realize soon after what the simplest solution is.  Gl on everything!